# Need to Change the Default URL on Mobile Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.4, plugin, mobile-web-design, mobile-detection

As you can probably see in my previous queestions, I'm new to Joomla with less than a year's worth of experience. I'm looking to start building out Mobile pages - but a previous developer left me in a difficult spot. The only thing he did was add a mobile plugin. However, when you visit our site ([ejgh.org](http://ejgh.org.)) from a mobile phone, it defaults to a blank page. I was able to build out a demo page under an article that was titled "Mobile Home", however it doesn't default when you pull up our site on a mobile device or tablet.

I've noticed the URL to the mobile page is http://ejgh.org/mobile-home. How can I get my website to default to that URL when accessing from a mobile device? It was working at one point but it since stopped and the developer is MIA. I've looked through the Mobile template and settings to see where I can change this but nothing is working. I'm running Joomla 3.3.

Hoping this made sense!

Answer (score 0):

Disregard, y'all! I found it - it's in the Menu settings. (Insert 'long day' excuse here)

Comment: Please consider to add more information. It would better help the community if you would name the plugin that is used to redirect to the mobile page, and what settings you changed to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Redirects made to this page are still broken. There's no big deal. The page template is badly written. There is no term such as **"mobile version".** Every website starts its life from desktop or mobile, no matter how far you try :)

I mark this topic as dead end.